# Inconsistent Roughness & Warping on Mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, materials, geometry-nodes

Hate to be the #9058609436043 person to ask a question about the damn donut render, but I'm trying to decipher the why behind these visual aberrations on my icing AND the clipping happening with sprinkles with rotations that are all set at 0. Any ideas? [image]

Comment: @moonboots ah, I see. My file is 7MB over their limit though. Can I link to the file via other means? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SmNqZgYu_rf11J13fyl5_JIhrqxfX8tA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @moonboots first of all, thank you for even taking the time to answer this. I really appreciate it. The first bit was simple enough, but the second bit involving overlapping meshes, is there a way to see this? I press L and the linked menu pops up, but I when I grab it the whole thing moves? I know I'm missing something obvious here :(

Comment: I'm talking about the torus under the icing: https://zupimages.net/up/22/12/tq6x.gif

Comment: @moonboots hmm, perhaps I'm not enabling something correct in here because I only have two Torus'(002 and 004) one is the donut base and the other is the top half that comprises of the icing. In edit mode I don't know how you're pulling all of those from the base 
https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=22/12/pt84.png

Comment: you need first to disable the Proportional Editing option on the top (blue sphere), then put your cursor on the top of the torus, press L to select the mesh, then G to move it away. Do it again beacuase there's a second mesh overlapping

Comment: @moonboots :( If I can't get it after this I'll leave you alone, lol 
https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=22/12/78zn.png

Comment: have you disabled the Proportional Editing option?

Comment: @moonboots yeah man, video recording attached: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YPjPm2hxbh5pWTH9li5YENn1skUvPH-O/view

Comment: Yes I saw it, I don't understand what's happening

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping faces, select all in *Edit* mode and merge by distance (<kbd>M</kbd>). You also have overlapping meshes on the top of the donut itself (press <kbd>L</kbd> to select one mesh, move it and delete).